# ASP.NET Ajax Text Box with Button not firing

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Hey just wondering if my syntax is wrong here

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" 
                        runat="server" 
                        UpdateMode="Always">
                        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:textbox id="searchProductName" runat="server"></asp:textBox> <asp:Button ID="btnProductSearch" runat="server" Text="Search Product Name"  CssClass="search" OnClick="ProductSearch_Click"  UseSubmitBehavior="true" CausesValidation="false" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
                 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnProductSearch" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and my OnClick method

```
Protected Sub ProductSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Filter by ProductName
    If searchProductName.Text.Length > 0 Then
        srcProductListPerCustomer.FilterExpression = " (productName like '%" + searchProductName.Text.ToString & "%')"
        productListTable.DataBind()
    Else
        srcProductListPerCustomer.FilterExpression = ""
        productListTable.DataBind()
    End If

End Sub
```

The problem is nothing is happening when I click on the button. The button works fine without the Ajax

Comment: Where's the productListTable? Outside of updatepanel?

Comment: Yes its a gridview..ah I see your point do i need to wrap it around the gridview to ?

Comment: Yes Stevie, and you don't need to have in updatepanel the trigger to update the panel. See the answer of Graham Clark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button doesn't need to be in an `UpdatePanel`. The controls in a `UpdatePanel` should be the controls that are to be *updated* asynchronously. Put your `UpdatePanel` around the `GridView` you're updating, and use the `AsyncPostBackTrigger` in the same way.

It's best to keep UdpatePanels as small as possible; the fewer controls inside them, the less HTML will be sent back from the server (less bandwidth, faster request/response time). PostBackTriggers can refer to controls outside of the UpdatePanel with no problems.

Comment: And I have multiple buttons on this screen that interact with the gridview I just put them all in trigger section below gridview ?

Comment: @StevieB: yep, just create an `AsyncPostBackTrigger` for each one.